# I can't see documents that I added in Sanity on the website and got the CORS error

Tags: reactjs, frontend, cors, sanity

I am developing a website using Sanity and React. I connected the Sanity to my project, added sanity id, token, etc. Also, I added schemas and can see these on the sanity desk. But when I add a new document and publish it on Sanity, I can't see the changes on my website.

I attached important files that I added to my project. I only can see the h2 with class name "head-text" in about.jsx file and can't see divs.

And also, I got some errors. I don't know if it's a reason of the problem but I got these errors:

[image: CORS Error]

index.js file:

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";


const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

client.js file:

```js
import sanityClient from '@sanity/client';
import imageUrlBuilder from '@sanity/image-url';

export const client = sanityClient({
    projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_SANITY_PROJECT_ID, 
    dataset: 'production',
    apiVersion: '2021-10-21',
    useCdn: true,
    token: process.env.REACT_APP_SANITY_TOKEN,
    //
});

const builder = imageUrlBuilder(client);

export const urlFor = (source) => builder.image(source);
```

/schemas/abouts.js file (for sanity):

```js
export default{
    name:'abouts',
    title:'Abouts',
    type: 'document',
    fields:[
        {
            name:'title',
            title:'Title',
            type:'string'
        },
        {
            name:'description',
            title:'Description',
            type:'string'
        },
        {
            name:'imgUrl',
            title:'ImgUrl',
            type: 'image',
            options: {
              hotspot: true,
            },
        },
        
    ]
}
```

App.js file:

```js
import React from 'react';

import { About, Footer, Header, Skills, Testimonial, Work } from './container';
 
import { Navbar } from './components';

import './App.scss';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className='app'>
      <Navbar />
      <Header />
      <About />
      <Work />
      <Skills />
      <Testimonial />
      <Footer />
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

/About.jsx file:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './About.scss';

import { motion } from 'framer-motion';
import { urlFor, client } from '../../client';
import { ArrowBackOutlined } from '@mui/icons-material';



const About = () => {
  const [abouts, setAbouts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const query = '*[_type == "abouts"]';

    client.fetch(query).then((data) => {
      setAbouts(data);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <h2 className="head-text">I Know that <span>Good Design</span> <br />means  <span>Good Business</span></h2>

      <div className="app__profiles">
        {abouts.map((about, index) => (
          <motion.div
            whileInView={{ opacity: 1 }}
            whileHover={{ scale: 1.1 }}
            transition={{ duration: 0.5, type: 'tween' }}
            className="app__profile-item"
            key={about.title + index}
          >
            <img src={urlFor(about.imgUrl)} alt={about.title} />
            <h2 className="bold-text" style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>{about.title}</h2>
            <p className="p-text" style={{ marginTop: 10 }}>{about.description}</p>
          </motion.div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default About
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you add your app's origin (be it localhost or production) to the CORS section of the Sanity project as described here https://www.sanity.io/docs/cors?

That's usually why people get these errors.

Comment: Thank your for your answer, I already added the localhost but it didn't change anything for me. I fixed with created Sanity Studio, added to CORS section of the Sanity and deployed. It works now.